# Recursive Copy of Directory

Tags: php, copy, dir

On my old VPS I was using the following code to copy the files and directories within a directory to a new directory that was created after the user submitted their form.

```
function copyr($source, $dest)
{
   // Simple copy for a file
   if (is_file($source)) {
      return copy($source, $dest);
   }

   // Make destination directory
   if (!is_dir($dest)) {
      mkdir($dest);
      $company = ($_POST['company']);
   }

   // Loop through the folder
   $dir = dir($source);
   while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) {
      // Skip pointers
      if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
         continue;
      }

      // Deep copy directories
      if ($dest !== "$source/$entry") {
         copyr("$source/$entry", "$dest/$entry");
      }
   }

   // Clean up
   $dir->close();
   return true;
}

copyr('Template/MemberPages', "Members/$company")
```

However now on my new VPS it will only create the main directory, but will not copy any of the files to it.  I don't understand what could have changed between the 2 VPS's?

Comment: Your code would be more readable if you indented every block.

Comment: May be the PHP version, try this [recursive copy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php#91256) function from php manual.

Comment: SIFE - Tried that one and it didn't work either.  So not sure what I am doing wrong.  But I just copy the code, input my source and destination paths, and make sure chmod is all set, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Jasom may be you don't have enough permission in destination directory to copy to it.

Comment: wtf are you doing with the $_POST global here? this kills the generic approach completely and makes the func unusable for me - but anyway there are good examples in the answers :)

Answer (score 86):

Try something like this:

```
$source = "dir/dir/dir";
$dest= "dest/dir";

mkdir($dest, 0755);
foreach (
 $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
  \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $item
) {
  if ($item->isDir()) {
    mkdir($dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathname());
  } else {
    copy($item, $dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathname());
  }
}
```

Iterator iterate through all folders and subfolders and make copy of files from `$source` to `$dest`

Comment: If you're using Zend Guard, be sure when using $iterator->getSubPathName() to call it as an anonymous function. What worked for me was: call_user_func_array (array ($iterator, "getSubPathName"), array ());

Comment: Thanks OzzyCzech Very Helpfull Script for.. but i also want to backing up my database kindly please tell about that process or write script or give me any link for that

Comment: might want to consider a 3rd parameter of true on the mkdir to recursively make the destination directory i.e.
mkdir($dest, 0755, true);
foreach (...

Comment: Does `RecursiveIteratorIterator` implements a `__call()` method that forwards `getSubPathName()` to the instance of the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` or how does that work?

Answer (score 16):

Could I suggest that (assuming it's a *nix VPS) that you just do a system call to `cp -r` and let that do the copy for you.

Answer (score 9):

I have changed Joseph's code (below), because it wasn't working for me. This is what works:

```
function cpy($source, $dest){
    if(is_dir($source)) {
        $dir_handle=opendir($source);
        while($file=readdir($dir_handle)){
            if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
                if(is_dir($source."/".$file)){
                    if(!is_dir($dest."/".$file)){
                        mkdir($dest."/".$file);
                    }
                    cpy($source."/".$file, $dest."/".$file);
                } else {
                    copy($source."/".$file, $dest."/".$file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dir_handle);
    } else {
        copy($source, $dest);
    }
}
```

[EDIT] added test before creating a directory (line 7)

Answer (score 9):

This function copies folder recursivley very solid. I've copied it from the comments section on [copy command of php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/function.copy.php)

```
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    @mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
}
```

Comment: For people of the future, I would recommend to put the body of this method in `if(is_dir($src)){ ..code.. }else{ copy($src, $dst); }`. This also prevents DoS on your server if you try to copy regular file using this method

Answer (score 7):

The [Symfony's FileSystem Component](https://github.com/symfony/Filesystem) offers a good error handling as well as recursive remove and other useful stuffs. Using @OzzyCzech's great answer, we can do a robust recursive copy this way:

```
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;

// ...

$fileSystem = new FileSystem();

if (file_exists($target))
{
    $this->fileSystem->remove($target);
}

$this->fileSystem->mkdir($target);

$directoryIterator = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($directoryIterator, \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($iterator as $item)
{
    if ($item->isDir())
    {
        $fileSystem->mkdir($target . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
    }
    else
    {
        $fileSystem->copy($item, $target . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
    }
}
```

Note: you can use this component as well as all other Symfony2 components standalone.

Comment: The Symfony Filesystem component has a [mirror](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html#mirror) method : `$filesystem->mirror('/path/to/source', '/path/to/target');`

Answer (score 6):

Here's what we use at our company:

```
static public function copyr($source, $dest)
{
    // recursive function to copy
    // all subdirectories and contents:
    if(is_dir($source)) {
        $dir_handle=opendir($source);
        $sourcefolder = basename($source);
        mkdir($dest."/".$sourcefolder);
        while($file=readdir($dir_handle)){
            if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
                if(is_dir($source."/".$file)){
                    self::copyr($source."/".$file, $dest."/".$sourcefolder);
                } else {
                    copy($source."/".$file, $dest."/".$file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dir_handle);
    } else {
        // can also handle simple copy commands
        copy($source, $dest);
    }
}
```

Comment: It needs to add if (!file_exists($dest."/".$sourcefolder)) check before mkdir($dest."/".$sourcefolder); in cases when folders are exists

Comment: almost worked for me.
but replaced like this.

    「copy($source."/".$file, $dest."/".$file);」  ⇒  「 copy($source."/".$file, $dest."/".$sourcefolder."/".$file);」

Answer (score 2):

```
function recurse_copy($source, $dest)
{
    // Check for symlinks
    if (is_link($source)) {
        return symlink(readlink($source), $dest);
    }

    // Simple copy for a file
    if (is_file($source)) {
        return copy($source, $dest);
    }

    // Make destination directory
    if (!is_dir($dest)) {
        mkdir($dest);
    }

    // Loop through the folder
    $dir = dir($source);
    while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) {
        // Skip pointers
        if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        // Deep copy directories
        recurse_copy("$source/$entry", "$dest/$entry");
    }

    // Clean up
    $dir->close();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OzzyCheck's is elegant and original, but he forgot the initial mkdir($dest);
See below. No copy command is ever provided with contents only. It must fulfill its entire role.

```
$source = "dir/dir/dir";
$dest= "dest/dir";

mkdir($dest, 0755);
foreach (
  $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
  RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $item) {
  if ($item->isDir()) {
    mkdir($dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
  } else {
    copy($item, $dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
  }
}
```

Comment: You should check if the dir exists before creating it.

Answer (score 1):

hmm. as that's complicated ))

```
function mkdir_recursive( $dir ){
  $prev = dirname($dir);
  if( ! file_exists($prev))
  {
    mkdir_recursive($prev);
  }
  if( ! file_exists($dir))
  {
     mkdir($dir);
  }
}

...
$srcDir = "/tmp/from"
$dstDir = "/tmp/to"
mkdir_recursive($dstDir);
foreach( $files as $file){
  copy( $srcDir."/".$file, $dstDir."/".$file);
}
```

`$file` - somthing like that `file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple recursive function to copy entire directories

source: http://php.net/manual/de/function.copy.php

```
<?php 
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    @mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just ask the OS to take care of this?

```
system("cp -r olddir newdir");
```

Done.

Comment: Not just OS dependent, but "system" call is usually disabled in production.

Comment: Not a good idea,never use shell in php unless you have to.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

/**
 * code by Nk (nk.have.a@gmail.com)
 */

class filesystem
{
    public static function normalizePath($path)
    {
        return $path.(is_dir($path) && !preg_match('@/$@', $path) ? '/' : '');      
    }

    public static function rscandir($dir, $sort = SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING)
    {
        $results = array();

        if(!is_dir($dir))
        return $results;

        $dir = self::normalizePath($dir);

        $objects = scandir($dir, $sort);

        foreach($objects as $object)
        if($object != '.' && $object != '..')
        {
            if(is_dir($dir.$object))
            $results = array_merge($results, self::rscandir($dir.$object, $sort));
            else
            array_push($results, $dir.$object);
        }

        array_push($results, $dir);

        return $results;
    }

    public static function rcopy($source, $dest, $destmode = null)
    {
        $files = self::rscandir($source);

        if(empty($files))
        return;

        if(!file_exists($dest))
        mkdir($dest, is_int($destmode) ? $destmode : fileperms($source), true);

        $source = self::normalizePath(realpath($source));
        $dest = self::normalizePath(realpath($dest));

        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            $file_dest = str_replace($source, $dest, $file);

            if(is_dir($file))
            {
                if(!file_exists($file_dest))
                mkdir($file_dest, is_int($destmode) ? $destmode : fileperms($file), true);
            }
            else
            copy($file, $file_dest);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

/var/www/websiteA/backup.php :

```
<?php /* include.. */ filesystem::rcopy('/var/www/websiteA/', '../websiteB'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should check user(group)**rights**. You should consider **chmod** for example, depending on **how you run** (su?)PHP. You could possibly also choose to modify your **php configuration**.

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues with the functions that I tested in the thread and here is a powerful function that covers everything. Highlights:

> 1. No need to have an initial or intermediate source directories. All of the directories up to the source directory and to the copied directories will be handled.
> 2. Ability to skip directory or files from an array. (optional) With the `global $skip;` skipping of files even under sub level directories are handled.
> 3. Full recursive support, all the files and directories in multiple depth are supported.

```
$from = "/path/to/source_dir";
$to = "/path/to/destination_dir";
$skip = array('some_file.php', 'somedir');

copy_r($from, $to, $skip);

function copy_r($from, $to, $skip=false) {
    global $skip;
    $dir = opendir($from);
    if (!file_exists($to)) {mkdir ($to, 0775, true);}
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if ($file == '.' OR $file == '..' OR in_array($file, $skip)) {continue;}
        
        if (is_dir($from . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)) {
            copy_r($from . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file, $to . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
        }
        else {
            copy($from . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file, $to . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursively copies files from source to target, with choice of overwriting existing files on the target.

```
function copyRecursive($sourcePath, $targetPath, $overwriteExisting) {
$dir = opendir($sourcePath);
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
    if ($file == "." || $file == "..") continue; // ignore these.

    $source = $sourcePath . "/" . $file;
    $target = $targetPath. "/" . $file;

    if (is_dir($source) == true) {
        // create the target directory, if it does not exist.
        if (file_exists($target) == false) @mkdir($target);
        copyRecursive($source, $target, $overwriteExisting);
    } else {
        if ((file_exists($target) == false) || ($overwriteExisting == true)) {
            copy($source, $target);
        }
    }
}
closedir($dir);
```

}