# CakePHP Console won't let me create files, returns error "sh: /touch: not found"

Tags: bash, shell, cakephp

I have set up the [CakePHP Console](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html) (CakePHP 2.5.3) and created the Shell `UpdateShell.php`:

```
<?php
class UpdateShell extends AppShell {

public function main() {

    exec('touch /test.tmp');

}
```

When I try to execute this Shell, it shows the error `sh: /touch: not found`

The same error occurs if I want to copy a file, then it says  `sh: /cp: not found`

Im trying to execute it the following way:

- log in with terminal: `ssh root@myserver.com`
- go to app folder: `cd /path_to_my_cakephp_folder/app/`
- execute cake shell: `Console/cake update`

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS.

Any ideas apprechiated, I've been trying for hours.

Comment: PHP has a [`touch()`](http://php.net/touch) function...

Comment: yea, but I need to copy files, I use `touch` for testing, it should be able to do that with the shell, I works when I type it in directly

Comment: [`copy()`](http://php.net/copy), [Recursive Copy of Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707806/recursive-copy-of-directory) ... I don't know anything about CakePHP, but you (almost) never need to execute shell commands in a highlevel language (like PHP).

Comment: sure its possible, but i need it in shell! I want to copy thousands of files, multiple times, takes forever with php, takes less than a second with shell. As I said the above is just an example that needs to work, once I got this working I can build my shell script which uses many shell commands, including `touch` and `cp`

Comment: If you have to execute shell commands, have you tried using the absolute path to the executable, e.g. `/usr/bin/touch`?

Comment: same error: `exec('/usr/bin/touch /test3333.tmp');` > `sh: /touch: not found`

Comment: The fact that the `sh` output prepends all your commands with a leading slash worries me. What kind of setup are you on? It looks like some sort of chrooted environment? In that case you'll need to use full paths for binaries that you actually have access to.